# Rendering image in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an issue to render my images from my './src/img' file and have no idea where i'm going wrong...

I have an object which have a key 'image' which return the file name (ie: 'filename.jpg'). As stated before, the images are stored in an 'img' folder in the 'src' one.

in my component, i return the image like this :

```
<div className='image'>
    <img src={require(`../img/${details.image}`)} alt={details.name} />
    {
        console.log(details.image)
    }
  </div>
```

i use the require function as i'm supposed to, (i think ?!^^) and indicates the folder and retrieve the image name with `${details.image}`.
As you can see i'm doing a console.log of details image which returns me the filenames without fail.

When i go into the console and check the rendering, i have no issue with the alt, but the src param gives me `[object Module]`

And that's where i'm kind of lost as to what happens and what i did wrong there.

Thanks by advance

Comment: require is not needed just add the path of the image in the string. And make sure you have img folder in the public path.

Comment: So i did as you said and it works fine. I tried to do a build just to check and no prob. Thank you very much !
(the render is now as follows : <img src={'../img/'+ details.image} alt={details.nom} />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of the require module, try importing the image as suggested by [creat-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) docs.

> import logo from './logo.jpeg';

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // <<<< image

console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;   // <<<<<< Adding to src attribute.
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i used the previous answer though, but yours is more than logical enough. I'd may have to use states i guess but i could have thought of it before hand ^^